# How to create a new variable of age based upon an existing numeric date born variable in sas?

Tags: sas

I want to create a numeric age variable using an existing numeric born date variable (MMDDYY10) in SAS. This "BORN" variable is numeric with a length of 8, the format is MMDDYY10. I'm assuming to use: age=today's date -BORN date. However, BORN date is like:-15226、-8803….I just don't understand why before these number, there is a minus signal. So what is the code to transfer to actual age?

I don't understand why before born date number, there is a minus signal. So how to use today's date minus born date of patient?

Answer (score 0):

SAS is using a number for date/time. Dates are defined as number of days between 1.1. 1960 and specified date, so dates before that time are negative. To translate it to a (for people) readable form, you have to use formats (for example MMDDYY10.)

Similarly time is a number of seconds since midnight of the current day. SAS time values are between 0 and 86400.

Your code would look like this:

```
data have;
    input born MMDDYY10.;
    format born MMDDYY10.;
    datalines;
03/17/2000
11/11/1988
08/11/1923
;
run;


data want;
        set have;
        age = floor((DATE()-born) / 365.25); 
run;
```

SAS will correctly translate your input (if you correctly used your formats) into numbers, which are easy for a program to calculate with.

Comment: Many thanks. The code runs successfully